# Repetitive dependencies for derived classes

Tags: c#, dependencies, derived-class

I have a base class:

```
class B { }
```

It has lots of dependencies:

```
public B(IFoo foo, IBar bar, IFooBar fooBar, IAlice alice, IBob bob) { }
```

I have lots of derived classes that look like:

```
public class D : B { }
```

But they need to satisfy the constructor of `B`, so they have dependencies:

```
public D(IFoo foo, IBar bar, IFooBar fooBar, IAlice alice, IBob bob)
    : base(foo, bar, fooBar, alice, bob) { }
```

Like I said, I have lots of these. And this seems bad. It's repetitive. A single code change to `B` ripples through lots of classes that all require a small, boring change.

Help?

Comment: Yes this does seem like you have a bad design possibly, do you have a more concrete example of why you think you need to do this? You shouldn't have the ripple effect if your base class is properly designed.

Comment: @awright18: How to avoid?

Comment: If you are using lots of interfaces you can combine/compose them. An interface can inherit from other interfaces. But the interface should only do what it needs to do so I'm guessing your derived objects are trying to do way too much.

Comment: @awright18: Okay, I'll be explicit. `B` represents a mapping rule from one type to another. The derived classes override certain subrules for various derived types. The dependencies for `B` are services it needs to carry out the mapping. So `B` and the `D`s do exactly one thing: map a certain type hierarchy to another type hierarchy. Too brief?

Comment: If you are doing object to object mapping I would highly recommend using a library like auto mapper, so you don't have to write this yourself as it can be very complex to handle all the cases, and you can just call it without have to do all the deriving.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would look at what changes you're making to B and if they're indicative of needing an extra subclass that most subclasses of B SHOULD subclass.

Having lots of constructor arguments isn't really a problem, just an inconvenience. You may wish to make a class to store all the base class arguments. When you need an instance of D, populate an instance of it and then pass that to D, which will then pass it to B and extract all its data.

```
public Bargs(IFoo foo, IBar bar, IFooBar fooBar, IAlice alice, IBob bob) { }
public B(Bargs myArgs){}
public D(Bargs myArgs) : B(myArgs){}
```